# Removing Underscore from text

Tags: python, regex

I am not sure where the small mistake is being made, but I want to remove all special characters including numbers from a text.

I used this:

```
def remove_special_chars(text):
    """ Method to remove special characters

    """

    print("original Text: {}\n".format(text))

    pattern=r'[^a-zA-z.\s]'
    text=re.sub(pattern,"",text)

    print("Modified text: {}".format(text))
```

And I get this:

```
remove_special_chars("Hi How_abc.com_are you!. hello_123@gmail.com?_")



   original Text: Hi How_abc.com_are you!. hello_123@gmail.com?_

   Modified text: Hi How_abc.com_are you. hello_gmail.com_
```

So while everything else seems to work fine, I am not sure why _ is not getting removed when it is not there in character class?

Comment: Because of `A-z` in `r'[^a-zA-z.\s]'` that creates a range that includes `_`. Replace with `A-Z`.

Comment: ... the answer is that `A-z` includes `_`

Comment: how A-z includes _? its hyphen and the other one is underscore?

Comment: Sorry I just got it. I wanted to put capital Z but just checked mistakably it has put small z in both and that is the issue. I wanted to to a-zA-Z. Thanks